# Using IUP on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, lua, iup

Are you guys suffered from this question when using IUP on MacOS?

```
Gizak-Pro:iup-3.6_MacOS107_bin Gizak$ ./iupview 
dyld: Library not loaded: /sw/lib/fontconfig2/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Gizak/Downloads/iup-3.6_MacOS107_bin/./iupview
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

So..How to make it work? That would be very helpful!

OS:Mac OS X 10.7.5
install lua5.1 by port
IUP version:3.6

Answer (score 4):

That application depends on some libraries that are not installed on your system.

In [the IUP documentation](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) you will be able to find a guide how to run IUP on MacOSX. The relevant section is in IUP / System / Drivers / GTK.

Answer (score 1):

The binary you're using is linking to a path provided by Fink, check the README.md in the download directory of IUP sf project.
You could either:

- install Fink and fullfill the dependencies
- rewrite the dependency using install_name_tool
- set DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH to match dependencies installed by another source